# How can I mock classmethod that is called by another classmethod?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, python-3.6

I have class with two class methods. Method A calls method B, processes his response and returns it. Method A is used by other code. I want to mock method B so that method A will call his mocked version just like in example below:

#### module1.py

```
class SomethingGetter:
    # method B - I want to mock it
    @classmethod
    def get_something(cls):
        return 'something'
    
    # method A - it should use response of mocked version of method A
    @classmethod
    def get_formatted_something(cls):
        return f'formatted {cls.get_something()}'
```

#### module2.py

```
from module1 import SomethingGetter

# this function should use SomethingGetter with mocked class mehotd
def something_printer():
    print(SomethingGetter.get_formatted_something())
```

#### module3.py

```
from unittest import mock
from module1 import SomethingGetter
from module2 import something_printer

# I want to use this function in test insted of SomethingGetter.get_something
def get_something_else():
    return SomethingGetter.get_something() + ' else'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mock.patch('module2.SomethingGetter', autospec=True) as patched:
        patched.get_something = get_something_else
        something_printer()
        # it prints <MagicMock name='SomethingGetter.get_formatted_something()' id='139753624280704'>;
        # but I expected that it would print "formatted something else"
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By patching `module2.SomethingGetter`, you've also caused `get_formatted_something()` to be patched.

Instead, you should only patch the `get_something()` method, storing a reference to the original:

```
original = SomethingGetter.get_something
with mock.patch.object(SomethingGetter, 'get_something', lambda: original() + ' else'):
    something_printer()
```

Comment: I was trying to do it in this way, but it causes exception `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. It occures because `get_something_else` uses `SomethingGetter.get_something`, which should be mocked. I solved this problem by making `get_something` module function instead of class method. But I want to know is there any solution in which I could remain `get_something` as class method.

Comment: @VasiliyKirstia My mistake, I didn't see that you were calling the original method. I've submitted an edit that I tested and confirmed is working.